# How to Select specific user from ListView in android

Tags: android, listview

I have student roll no store in ListView.Now I want to select and click on roll no so it show me the name of that student.For example if I have roll no=1,when I click on this it should to show me name like a,and if I click on roll no 2,it should to show me name like b,and so on....

```
ArrayList<String> student = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_selectable_list_item, student);
ListView list = new(ListView)findViewById(R.id.ll);

public void dd(View view){
    if (res.getCount() == 0) {
        // show message
        showMessage("Error", "Nothing found");
        return;
    }

    while (res.moveToNext()) {
        String roll = "Roll No1:" + res.getString(0);
        String rolll = "Roll NO2:" + res.getString(1);
        String rollk = "Roll NO3:" + res.getString(2);
        student.add(roll);
        student.add(rolll);
        student.add(rollk);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}


list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), student.get(i), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    }

});
```

it work correctly but show same message for all.I also used the switch statment for this but goes to alot of bunches of case like case 0,case 1,case 2 etc.
And I also used the if condition but it also goes to buches of if condition.So I want a specific way to handle this.And to click on roll no 2 to  show one student name and to click on roll no3 to show another student name.

Comment: What does res look like?

Comment: res is fine it work fine .its data from database

Comment: Well it isn't "fine" your onClickListener is correct. So the issue is in how you are populating the array list student. It would be helpful to people trying to helpful if you showed res.

Comment: public Cursor getallthird_table()
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res=db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_THIRD_NAME,null);
        return res;
    }

Comment: res=mydb.getallthird_table();
       // res = mydb.getAllDatazz_second();
        if (res.getCount() == 0) {
            // show message
            showMessage("Error", "Nothing found");

            return;
        }

Comment: I've provided an answer so that I could use a code block. I really think you are using cursor incorrectly I've tried to add comments to the code so you can see what your code is currently doing. Also as mentioned in the answer I think you should move set adapter out of your loop. And you should wait to create your adapter after filling the list or call notifyDataSetChanged on it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have something confused with your cursor. It's hard to say without seeing your database setup. Lets look at what you currently have

```
//I would add res.moveToStart() here just to be safe.
while (res.moveToNext()) { //This should probably be a do while otherwise you'll skip the first entry

        //This is where things seem to be not right these next three statements get columns 1, 2 and 3 of your database.
        //So this would mean your database structure is 
        //|roll|roll|roll|
        //is this really correct?
        //I would think for performance you would have an index and something like
        //|id|roll name|roll email?|
        //with that setup you would simply do
        String rollName = "Roll NO2:" + res.getString(1);
        student.add(rollName);
}

//I would also instantiate adapter here now that your list is populate or call notifyDataSetChanged() on it
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_selectable_list_item, student);

//This should also be outside of your loop you don't need to call this every time. 
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```